# Webpack4 in production mode, does not uglify variable names in state of a React.Component?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, production

The varialble names in state of a react component will not be changed in production mode by webpack 4.

I try "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.3", but does not make a difference.

For instance,

```js
class Counter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {count: props.initialCount};
  }
  // ...
}
```

I want in production, the state name `count` is been uglyfied.
I expect something like,

```js
this.state = {c:props.initialCount};
```

webpack.config.js is as follows, 
// load packages

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
```

// define the path

```
const STATIC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname,
    'static',
    'app', 'js');
const SOURCE_DIR = path.resolve(STATIC_DIR, 'src');
```

```
module.exports = {
    mode: "production",
    devtool: 'source-map',
```

// define entry

```
    entry: {
        plugin: path.resolve(SOURCE_DIR, 'index.js')
    },
```

// define output

```
    output: {
        filename: '[name]-2.4.0.js',
        path: STATIC_DIR
    },
```

Here is the important part,

```
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?/,
                include: SOURCE_DIR,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        // compact: false,
                        // presets: ["es2015", "react"],
                        plugins: ['transform-class-properties']
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    externals: {
        jquery: 'jQuery'
    }
};
```

Comment: webpack config please

Comment: Why do you want this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't believe that's going to happen. The uglifier can't know how `this.state` is used and. For instance, you could index into it in a dynamic manner:

```
this.state = {count: 8};
console.log(this.state['c' + 'ount']);  // 8
```

Even if it could understand that that's not going to happen within the component, you could do

```
somethingElse(this.state);
```

and whatever `somethingElse()` is, it probably couldn't make heads or tails of `this.state` if its keys were minified.

I don't recommend it, but one way to achieve this in a roundabout way is to use string variables for keys and [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)  –

```
const COUNT_KEY = (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? 'c' : 'count');
this.state = {[COUNT_KEY]: 8};
console.log(this.state[COUNT_KEY]);
```

which might get uglified into e.g. this in production:

```
const t = "c";
this.state = {[t]: 8};
console.log(this.state[t]);
```

Comment: thanks for your explanation and the solution. Do you agree that this.state is locally valid w.r.t. a single jsx file or w.r.t. a React component? So why it cannot be uglyfied since the outsiders do not depend on those names?

Comment: The uglifier is simply not smart enough to be able to deduce it's not used anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

you can put condition like this

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    this.state = {c:props.initialCount};     //execute in production time
} else {
    this.state = {count: props.initialCount};
}
```

Comment: This is not a good idea. It will make everything way too complex.

Comment: yes but for above requirement , this one is suitable.